# How do you see your viewer items in R studio?

Tags: r, viewer

How can I see previous tables that I generated in the viewer instead of only the most recent thing that I ran? For example if I've run several tables and changed one or two things and I wanted to be able to compare them side by side, how do I see them both? I'm thinking about how I can scroll through an SPSS output file.

I'm not sure if this is a code thing or a settings thing. Opening a new window doesn't seem to do anything. Refreshing the viewer doesn't seem to change anything.

I can put things in the viewer no problem using view() or expss_output_viewer or out="viewer".

I can only seem to get it to display the most recent table I ran.

Comment: It seems r notebooks are better suited for your needs than regular scripts: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/notebook.html

Answer (score 0):

Click the arrows in the upper left of the viewer pane to see previously plotted tables.

[Image of viewer pane with arrows highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY5NH.png)

Using flextable

```
flextable(mtcars)
```

[image: flextable table has arrows]

Using expss

```
expss_output_viewer()
as.etable(mtcars)
```

[image: expss table has no arrows]

Comment: Thanks, but the arrows, the zoom, and the export do not show up in my viewer pane, I just have the remove current item, the broom, and the the show in new window button. How do you get the arrows and other icons to show up?

Comment: Which version of RStudio do you have (Help > About RStudio)?

Comment: I have version 1.1.463. Maybe I just need to update?

Comment: Eh you can try but, 1.1.463 should work.  Please do note that the arrows only show up when there's something in the viewer pane.  If it's empty only the three icons you mentioned (remove current, broom and show in new window) are visible.

Out of curiosity do you have the arrows, zoom, etc. in your plot pane?

Comment: And it's there for help. But for the viewer it's not even like it's there and grayed out. It's just not there at all. I updated to version 1.2.1335 too.

Comment: Hmm - I can reproduce this now, using tables made with expss (which I see you're also using above).  If I make tables with flextable (another html table building package)  they work fine - the arrows are visible in the view pane.  I'll add images to the main post.

Comment: Thanks for working through this with me! It was driving me crazy!

Comment: Might be worth posting as a bug to the expss github here: https://github.com/gdemin/expss/issues